# Poor graphics performance on 3840 x 2160 resolution using NVidia GeForce GTX 1080, nvidia-375 proprietary driver, HDMI-HDMI cable, and Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, 17.04, 4k-monitor

I am experiencing very poor graphics performance on the following configuration. I've switched many different drivers all with the same result. 2560 x 1440 seems to work fine:

- 3840 x 2160 resolution
- NVidia GeForce GTX 1080
- nvidia-375 proprietary driver
- HDMI-HDMI cable
- Ubuntu 17.04

Both the keyboard cursor and the mouse seem to lag very much. Chrome is particularly bad at switching tabs (graphics take a long time to load). Moreover, switching workspaces is very slow.

Comment: Not only the port but also cables should be HDMI >= 2.0 for 4K signal. Did you try with the display port?

Comment: @Takkat I believe I have the correct cables because it works fine on Windows. I did not try display port because the monitor has speakers that I also use through HDMI.